# Tidy layout in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an application that allows the user to enter in information for sales at a party hire store and I've come across an issue.
Edit: I've tried using sticky and many other placement tools but nothing has seemed to work so far.

When I append more than one set of data to my dictionary and then press the print results button, all of the entered data is really close to each other.
Here is the code:

```py
# Party Gear Hire Shop
from tkinter import *
# Makes graphics better, if causing issues feel free to remove (up to dashed line) #
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Data
# Table where dataNeeded is kept
dataNeeded = {}
type(dataNeeded)
dataNeeded["Position"] = []
dataNeeded["fName"] = []
dataNeeded["lName"] = []
dataNeeded["item"] = []
dataNeeded["amount"] = []

trackerNum = 0

# Commands


def doAppend():
    global trackerNum
    global dataNeeded
    trackerNum += 1
    dataNeeded["Position"] += [trackerNum]
    dataNeeded["fName"] += [nameFirstEntry.get()]
    dataNeeded["lName"] += [nameLastEntry.get()]
    dataNeeded["item"] += [itemHiredEntry.get()]
    dataNeeded["amount"] += [amountHiredEntry.get()]


def doPrintResults():
    resultsWindow = Toplevel(root)
    resultsWindow.title("Receipts")

    resultsFrame = LabelFrame(resultsWindow, text="Current Receipts", padx=10, pady=10)
    resultsFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)

    resultsHeader = Label(resultsFrame, text="Receipt No:", padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader1 = Label(resultsFrame, text="First Name:", padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader1.grid(row=1, column=0,  padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader1_5 = Label(resultsFrame, text="Last Name:", padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader1_5.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader2 = Label(resultsFrame, text="Item:", padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader3 = Label(resultsFrame, text="Quantity:", padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
    resultsHeader3.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)

    rowPlacement = -1
    for x in dataNeeded:
        rowPlacement += 1
        nameLabel = Label(resultsFrame, text=dataNeeded[x], padx=2.5, pady=2.5)
        nameLabel.grid(column=trackerNum+1, row=rowPlacement, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)


root = Tk()

root.title("Party Hire Store")  # Titles window

# Entry Area -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entryAreaFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Add a transaction", padx=10, pady=10)
entryAreaFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=5, padx=10, pady=10)

nameFirstLabel = Label(entryAreaFrame, text="First Name:")
nameFirstLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
nameFirstEntry = Entry(entryAreaFrame)
nameFirstEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, padx=1, pady=1)

nameLastLabel = Label(entryAreaFrame, text="Last Name:")
nameLastLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
nameLastEntry = Entry(entryAreaFrame)
nameLastEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, padx=1, pady=1)

itemHiredLabel = Label(entryAreaFrame, text="Item Hired:")
itemHiredLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
itemHiredEntry = Entry(entryAreaFrame)
itemHiredEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, padx=1, pady=1)

amountHiredLabel = Label(entryAreaFrame, text="Quantity:")
amountHiredLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
amountHiredEntry = Entry(entryAreaFrame)
amountHiredEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=1, padx=1, pady=1)

doAppendButton = Button(entryAreaFrame, text="Append Details", padx=2.5, pady=2.5, command=doAppend)
doAppendButton.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
doPrintButton = Button(entryAreaFrame, text="Print Receipt", padx=2.5, pady=2.5, command=doPrintResults)
doPrintButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Now, what I'm asking for is how to make it so that for any piece of data that is entered, When I print the results, it prints neatly on a new window, which can be closed separately.
However, any other suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated as I look to further my skills in python, and in programming as a whole so any help is useful.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking us for a design?

Comment: You have put a list, for example `dataNeeded["fName"]`, in a column.  I think you want to put each item in the list in separate column instead.

Comment: Are you looking for `ttk.Treeview`?

Comment: Just so You know. There is a way easier and better way to organize your dictionary and those lists. Basically fisrt of You could just do this `data_needed = {"var 1": [], "var 2": []}` and so on, then the second thing is this `data_needed["var 1"].append(whatever)` and so on and that would also mean that You don't need to use `global data_needed` in that function.